# Get element out of window area

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, window, viewport

I'm using `tympunus nlform` in which dropdown popups come according to there parent position. So some of popup elements are getting out of `window`, basically it is getting cut from right side.

Not possible with `css` `right` positioning because any elements can come at any place.

So, what I want to get only *out of viewport* pixels with JS and `right` position it only *out of viewport area*.

Reference:

[image]

In what way it is possible?

also find [**fiddle demo nl form**](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/2dgmo4za/) which dropdowns goes out of view. (*try resize view window and see*).

Answer (score 0):

Change the left property

```
.nl-field ul {
left:-2em;//or more
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2dgmo4za/2/

Comment: My reason was to explain in details. I can not do this with only `css`. Because you'll never know which elements can go out of view in which window width. So I want when it goes out of viewport then cut area should get `position`. For example: If a element is getting cut 30px from right then I should get `right:-30px;` otherwise not.

Comment: you will need to test if the overed field is near the border of the window